# JSON.Net "Could not read query operator" in SelectTokens

Tags: json.net, jsonpath

I'm trying to get some info from some JSON I got from [magicthegathering.io](http://magicthegathering.io/) using the [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens_1.htm) method in JSON.Net. However, when I try to do this I get an error "Could not read query operator".

Here's the code I'm using:

```
JToken jtoken = JToken.Parse(
    @"{""cards"":[{""name"":""Krark-Clan Engineers"",""manaCost"":""{3}{R}"",""cmc"":4,""colors"":[""Red""],""type"":""Creature — Goblin Artificer"",""types"":[""Creature""],""subtypes"":[""Goblin"",""Artificer""],""rarity"":""Uncommon"",""set"":""5DN"",""text"":""{R}, Sacrifice two artifacts: Destroy target artifact."",""flavor"":""\""Well, I jammed the whatsit into the whackdoodle, but I think I broke the thingamajigger.\"""",""artist"":""Pete Venters"",""number"":""70"",""power"":""2"",""toughness"":""2"",""layout"":""normal"",""multiverseid"":50201,""imageUrl"":""http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=50201&type=card"",""foreignNames"":[{""name"":""喀勒克族机械工"",""language"":""Chinese Simplified"",""multiverseid"":81620},{""name"":""Ingénieurs du clan Krark"",""language"":""French"",""multiverseid"":80795},{""name"":""Ingenieure des Krark-Clans"",""language"":""German"",""multiverseid"":80960},{""name"":""Ingegneri di Krark-Clan"",""language"":""Italian"",""multiverseid"":81290},{""name"":""クラーク族の技師"",""language"":""Japanese"",""multiverseid"":80630},{""name"":""Engenheiros do Clã-de-Krark"",""language"":""Portuguese (Brazil)"",""multiverseid"":81455},{""name"":""Ingenieros del clan Krark"",""language"":""Spanish"",""multiverseid"":81125}],""printings"":[""5DN""],""originalText"":""{R}, Sacrifice two artifacts: Destroy target artifact."",""originalType"":""Creature — Goblin Artificer"",""legalities"":[{""format"":""Commander"",""legality"":""Legal""},{""format"":""Freeform"",""legality"":""Legal""},{""format"":""Legacy"",""legality"":""Legal""},{""format"":""Mirrodin Block"",""legality"":""Legal""},{""format"":""Modern"",""legality"":""Legal""},{""format"":""Prismatic"",""legality"":""Legal""},{""format"":""Singleton 100"",""legality"":""Legal""},{""format"":""Tribal Wars Legacy"",""legality"":""Legal""},{""format"":""Vintage"",""legality"":""Legal""}],""id"":""a4d05fd27ec5d7df470e91218f1ca885eda4f0c6""}]}"
);

var foundTokens = jtoken.SelectTokens(@"$..cards[?(@.name=""Krark - Clan Engineers"")].imageUrl", true);
if (foundTokens.Any())
{
    string selected = foundTokens.Last().ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Found: " + selected);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found nothing!");
}
```

([Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fzyVFW) is a fiddle with the same code as shown above.)

When I try to get the same path using online JSONPath testing tools ([here](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) or [here](http://www.jsonquerytool.com/) for example) it works as expected.

Why doesn't this work in JSON.Net? And how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. You have to use `==` for string comparison; `=` is only for numerical values.
2. You have to enclose your string in single quotes.

e.g. `@.name=='Krark - Clan Engineers')`

[forked fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/riqhEA)

Comment: What should I do if the name includes a single quote? Such as `Kodama's Reach`?

Comment: $.[?(@.param=="+param+")]  Where my param is db driven or passed value.. But its not working. Can anyone tell how to achieve this?